# How to pass to a generic function class type that implements certan interface?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I want to create a  generic function with signature like this : `void funcName<T>()` where `T` would be required to be an implementation of some particular interface I want. How to make such check? How to pass to a generic function class type that implements certan interface?

So I create some `public interface IofMine {}` and I try to create a function like `public static void funcName<T>() where T : IofMine { var a = new T}` and sadly I get:

> Error:    Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it
>   does not have the new() constraint

What shall I do to make class types my function receives not only be of my desired interface but also have a constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to require that the generic parameter have a default constructor, specify `new()` as part of the generic constraint.

```
public static void funcName<T>() where T : IofMine, new()
{
    T a = new T();
}
```

You can only use this to require a default (i.e., no parameters) constructor. You can't require a constructor taking a string parameter, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
public void FuncName<T>(...) 
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    ...
}
```

This creates a constraint on the type parameter `T` so that any type used when calling the method must implement `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you declare it:

```
// Let's say that your function takes
// an instance of IMyInterface as a parameter:
void funcName<T>(T instance) where T : IMyInterface {
    instance.SomeInterfaceMethodFromMyInterface();
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
IMyInterface inst = new MyImplOfMyInterface();
funcName(inst);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correct, you need to use constraints of generic:

```
public interface TestInterface
{
}

public void func<T>()
    where T : TestInterface
{ 

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx